# How to combine multiple models into one view template in django

Tags: python, django

I have two models

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = RichTextField(max_length=1000000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank = True)
    image =  ResizedImageField(size=[250, 200], upload_to='img')
```

and

```
class Politics(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = RichTextField(max_length=1000000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank = True)
    image =  ResizedImageField(size=[250, 200], upload_to='img',blank = True)
```

I want to combine them both into one template view and render them on the index.html
Here is my view function

```
def index(request):
    politics = Politics.objects.all()
    return render(request,
    'index.html',
    {'politics':politics, 'posts': Post.objects.all()})
```

index.html (posts part)

```
<section id="posts" class="posts">
      <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
        <div class="row g-5">
          {% for post in posts reversed %}
          {% if forloop.counter < 5 %}
            <div class="post-entry-1 col-lg-2 box mx-1">
              <a href="/post/{{post.id}}"><img src="{{post.image.url}}" class="post_img"></a>
                <div>
                  <div class="post-meta"><span class="date">{{post.category}}</span> <span class="mx-1">&bullet;</span> <span>{{post.created_at}}</span></div>
                  <h2><a href="/post/{{post.id}}">{{post.title}}</a></h2>
                </div>
              <p class="mb-4 d-block">{{post.body|truncatewords:75}}</p>

              <div class="d-flex align-items-center author">
                <div class="photo"><img src="{% static 'assets/img/person-1.jpg' %}" alt="" class="img-fluid"></div>
                <div class="name">
                  <h3 class="m-0 p-0">OlePundit</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

(politics part)

```
 <div class="row">
       {% for politic in politics%}
       {% if forloop.counter < 11 %}
       <div class="post-entry-1 col-2 mx-1">
           <a href="/politicalpost/{{politic.id}}"><img src="{{politic.image.url}}" alt="" class="post_img"></a>
           <div class="post-meta">
               <span class="date">{{politic.category}}</span> 
               <span class="mx-1">&bullet;</span> 
               <span>{{politic.created_at}}</span>
           </div>
           <h2 class="mb-2"><a href="/politicalpost/{{politic.id}}">{{politic.title}}</a></h2>
           <span class="author mb-3 d-block">Ole Pundit</span>
           <p class="mb-4 d-block">{{politic.body| safe | truncatewords:20}}</p>
       </div>
       {% endif %}  
       {% endfor %}
     </div>
```

However, only the 'politics' object is being rendered. What could be wrong?

Comment: Show html, you are probably rendering it wrong.

Comment: Added the template files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this or the problem will be in template file

```py
def index(request):
    politics = Politics.objects.all()
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request,
    'index.html',
    {'politics':politics, 'posts': posts})
```

Comment: I had already tried that, let me add the template files

Comment: For some reason this worked. After re-writing the code this way, and removing the urls for politics and posts from the url.py, since I had previously created separate template views for them

Comment: @Felicity however clearer, this definitely didn't matter, problem had to be somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah the problem was probably in the url.py, thats the only other file I changed.